# PHP/SQL Beginner

Tags: php, sql

I have set up a table with attributes work1,work2,...,work11. I want to join them all in one array and then filter out any double entries. Where is the mistake in this code? I'd guess in this line `$row[${'work'.$i}];` but I can't figure out the correct way of writing this...

```
$work_list = array();
for ($i=1; $i <= 11 ; $i++) {
    $query_work = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT ${'work'.$i} FROM Test;"); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_work)) {
        $work_list[]= $row[${'work'.$i}];
    }
}

$work_list=array_merge(array_unique($work_list));
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place a value consisting of a constant string and a numeric variable into a larger string, just place the constant part directly into the outer string and then refer to the variable:

```
$query_work = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT work$i FROM Test;");
```

Alternatively, you can use string concatenation:

```
$query_work = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT work" . $i . " FROM Test;");
```

Since your `$row` array accepts string keys, you can access the column you're interested in similarly: either using

```
$work_list[] = $row["work$i"];
```

or using

```
$work_list[] = $row["work" . $i];
```

However, it might make more sense to fetch all the work items simultaneously from the database:

```
$work_list = array();
$work_names = array();
for ($i=1; $i <= 11 ; $i++) {
    $work_names[] = "work$i";
}
$work_name_string = implode(', ', $work_names);
$query_work = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT $work_name_string FROM Test;"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_work)) {
    for ($i=1; $i <= 11 ; $i++) {
        $work_list[]= $row["work$i"];
    }
}

$work_list=array_merge(array_unique($work_list));
```